# Условный тип переменной Delphi

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

Скрин проблемы:

[image]

Уже по-всякому пытался его использовать (вводил оригинал, заменял на integer, byte), все равно компилятор выдаёт ошибку. Помогите разобраться.  Если можно где то объявить Typel, то где именно это можно сделать ?

Оригинал: https://yadi.sk/i/20LpgCjYddULo  Для просмотра лучше скачать.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что ссылка протухла, и вопрос не подлежит восстановлению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотри выше по коду, у тебя этот Typel описан где-то. Со скрина понять нельзя, возможно,  это просто двумерный массив.

Comment: Да, посмотрел процедуры со скрина, 99% это двумерный массив типа ИНТ.

Comment: @savro Вот оригинал https://yadi.sk/i/20LpgCjYddULo Для просмотра лучше скачать

Answer (score 1):

А оригинал какой? Судя по тому, что указано в задании, это двумерный массив из **real** значений: array of array of real; И скорей всего статический, так как не видно нигде инициализации его размерности. Значит: array [1..10, 1..10] of real;

Comment: @Rang Вот оригинал https://yadi.sk/i/20LpgCjYddULo Для просмотра лучше скачать